# Does React Reconciliation works in this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Here array updates are mage immutable and will only create new array rather than updating the old array.

So in this Child Component `Item` should only be called once a/c to the new array value(index) but its called multiple times.

Code Example :

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    arr: [10]
  };

  updateArray = () => {
    console.log("updateArray");
    let { arr } = this.state;
    this.setState({ arr: [...arr, 20] });
  };

  render() {
    const { arr } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map((el, index) => {
          console.log("sasasa", index);
          return <Item el={el} key={index} />;
        })}
        <input type={"button"} value={"submit"} onClick={this.updateArray} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Item");
    return <div>{this.props.el}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);`
```

Console Output would look like this on clicking button third time

```
Item 
Item 
Item
```

Here we can see the `Item` component is rendered 3 times for all the elements in the array;

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/m9w54lyjy)

Comment: on every button click you are adding `20` to it, so everytime it will print `Item` as many times as number of elements in your array. And this is the expected behavior of react. I didn't get what is your expected behavior.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I warn you that I'm not 100% sure, but here's my answer.
When you update `App` Component, its `render()` method will call several time the `Item` Component, which will call its `render()` method (which is the one that displays `"Item"`.

Now, `render()` method AND Component are nothing but a function, thus, when called, they are executed: this is JavaScript, there is no React magic in between (not even the reconciliation).

But then, when React magic (in this case Reconciliation) kicks in? Take a look at this gif in which I've recorded the DOM element browser while using your codesandbox:
[image]

As you can see, when I click on the submit button, thank to the reconciliation, not all the `div` element are updated, but just the last one, since it's the new one.
This happens because, thanks to the `key` prop that you have assigned to the `div`, React recognize the old `div`, see that they haven't changed, thus does not modify the DOM for those `div`.

So, to conclude, reconciliation and React `render()` method are two separate things, running in two different moment.

Does this answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

React Reconciliation states that by comparing the `key` prop of every `Item` React won't have to destroy the DOM nodes and create them again on every render if they match with the previous state of the array. It will still go through every item in the array (this is why you get `console.logs` for every item) but the it won't do the costly operation (recreating DOM nodes) if it sees matching key values.